# How to correct an XML validation issue

Tags: xml, dtd

I tried to validate some XML code below, but it threw an error:

```
        <m1-3-administrative-information>
          <leaf ID="r4" checksum="da14dd2b9a71a8999b633cb7ab514d01" checksum-type="md5" operation="new" xlink:href="administrative-information.pdf" xlink:type="simple">
            <title>Administrative Information</title>
          </leaf>

          <m1-3-2-field-copy-certification>
              <leaf ID="r12" checksum="17bfd2aa55599391b7019e4160e58de5" checksum-type="md5" operation="new" xlink:href="field-copy-certification.pdf" xlink:type="simple">
                <title>field-copy-certification</title>
              </leaf>
          </m1-3-2-field-copy-certification>

          <m1-3-3-debarment-certification>
              <leaf ID="r8" checksum="341ab4bfb48b939992a27d9bdbf5548c" checksum-type="md5" operation="new" xlink:href="debarment-certification.pdf" xlink:type="simple">
                <title>debarment-certification</title>
              </leaf>
          </m1-3-3-debarment-certification>
        </m1-3-administrative-information>
```

> ERROR: Element m1-3-administrative-information content does not follow the DTD, expecting 
>   (m1-3-1-contact-sponsor-applicant-information* , m1-3-2-field-copy-certification* , m1-3-3-debarment-certification* , m1-3-4-financial-certification-and-disclosure* , m1-3-5-patent-and-exclusivity* , m1-3-6-tropical-disease-priority-review-voucher*), 
>   got (leaf m1-3-2-field-copy-certification m1-3-3-debarment-certification m1-3-5-patent-and-exclusivity )

If I remove this piece of code below from the script, the error disappears:

```
      <leaf ID="r4" checksum="da14dd2b9a71a8999b633cb7ab514d01" checksum-type="md5" operation="new" xlink:href="administrative-information.pdf" xlink:type="simple">
        <title>Administrative Information</title>
      </leaf>
```

This piece of code is a link to a pdf, and it's necessary for me to keep it in the script however. Therefore, I'm looking for some help in how to incorporate this leaf above without throwing an error during the validation. I am restricted from modifying the DTD file.

Therefore, my best guess is that either there is some XML code which will enable me to do this, or the DTD does not allow for it and I have no other choice than to place the link into a child node.

Thank you for your help. The DTD is below for reference.

```
<!ELEMENT m1-3-administrative-information (m1-3-1-contact-sponsor-applicant-
information*, m1-3-2-field-copy-certification*, m1-3-3-debarment-
certification*, m1-3-4-financial-certification-and-disclosure*, m1-3-5-
patent-and-exclusivity*, m1-3-6-tropical-disease-priority-review-voucher*)>

<!ATTLIST m1-3-administrative-information>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-contact-sponsor-applicant-information (m1-3-1-1-change-of-
address-or-corporate-name*, m1-3-1-2-change-in-contact-agent*, m1-3-1-3-
change-in-sponsor*, m1-3-1-4-transfer-of-obligation*, m1-3-1-5-change-in
ownership-of-an-application-or-reissuance-of-license*)>

<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-contact-sponsor-applicant-information>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-1-change-of-address-or-corporate-name ((leaf | node-
extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-1-change-of-address-or-corporate-name>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-2-change-in-contact-agent ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-2-change-in-contact-agent>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-3-change-in-sponsor ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-3-change-in-sponsor>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-4-transfer-of-obligation ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-4-transfer-of-obligation>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-1-5-change-in-ownership-of-an-application-or-reissuance-of-
license ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-1-5-change-in-ownership-of-an-application-or-reissuance-of-
license>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-2-field-copy-certification ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-2-field-copy-certification>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED

<!ELEMENT m1-3-3-debarment-certification ((leaf | node-extension)*)>
<!ATTLIST m1-3-3-debarment-certification>
ID ID #IMPLIED
xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to my problem. I figured out that the DTD does now allow for me to add the linking attribute in at the level I'm looking for.

When it is in fact valid, the DTD specifies ((leaf | node-extension)*). In other words, the link I'd like to use must be nested further into hierarchy to be valid.